# Javascript/JQuery having an alert pop up when page loads won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alert

I'm trying to get an alert to pop up when my web page loads. The Javascript code works when inline coded to the html code, but when placed into a separate file and linked/saved as script.js nothing happens. Can anyone by chance see what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code, if you happen to see where I'm going wrong I would really appreciate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("Welcome!);
      });
```

```css
background-color:Teal;

}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: Gold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 25pt;
}
#p1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 300px;
}
#p2 {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#p3 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 300px;
}
#img1 {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
#img2 {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
a:link {
  color: gold;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: gold;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  color: lime;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    "Cute Cats"
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
  <h1> Cute Cats </h1>


  <p id="p1"> <img src="Tulip.jpg" alt="Cute Cat-Tulip" id="img1"> Find box a little too small and curl up with fur hanging out lick arm hair or sweet beast swat at dog, and chirp at birds that box? i can fit in that box. Spit up on light gray carpet instead of adjacent
    linoleum. Spill litter box, scratch at owner, destroy all furniture, especially couch find empty spot in cupboard and sleep all day, licks paws ptracy,intently sniff hand, or really likes hummus weigh eight pounds but take up a full-size bed. Chew
    the plant. Bleghbleghvomit my furball really tie the room together hiss and stare at nothing then run suddenly away and warm up laptop with butt lick butt fart rainbows until owner yells pee in litter box hiss at cats stretch, ooh, are those your
    $250 dollar sandals?

  </p>


  <p id="p2"> <img src="Tikki.jpg" alt="Cute Cat-Tikki" id="img2"> Slap kitten brother with paw spread kitty litter all over house, i could pee on this if i had the energy purr when being pet for nya nya nyan. Touch water with paw then recoil in horror eat all the
    power cords for chill on the couch table, annoy the old grumpy cat, start a fight and then retreat to wash when i lose so scratch me there, elevator butt refuse to come home when humans are going to bed; stay out all night then yowl like i am dying
    at 4am. Eat the rubberband the cat was chasing the mouse so demand to be let outside at once, and expect owner to wait for me as i think about it yet taco cat backwards spells taco cat furrier and even more furrier hairball for groom forever, stretch
    tongue and leave it slightly out, blep stand in front of the computer screen. Red light attracts my eyes, light must die, attack!

  </p>


  <p id="p3"> <img src="Maddi.jpg" alt="Cute Cat-Maddison" id="img1"> More napping, more napping all the napping is exhausting. Fish i must find my red catnip fishy fish who's the baby pet me pet me don't pet me scratch need to chase tail, but intently stare at the
    same spot, or i like frogs and 0 gravity. Meow to be let out thinking longingly about tuna brine or catasstrophe scratch, yet stare at wall turn and meow stare at wall some more meow again continue staring take a big fluffing crap cough hairball on
    conveniently placed pants. Lounge in doorway hiding behind the couch until lured out by a feathery toy. Sit on human give attitude, or meow go back to sleep owner brings food and water tries to pet on head, so scratch get sprayed by water because
    bad cat or lick butt. Stare at ceiling.

  </p>

</body>
```

Again any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are including jQuery twice, that's not good

Comment: Open your browser console and check for errors. If you have any please return and edit/update your question to include the error(s) that you see. Thank you

Comment: Look for [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) errors first. -- For sure, you load jQuery twice and that's a fail.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the **end double quotes** in your alert. I fixed it for
    you in the snippet below.

**Note:** It's *redundant* to include jQuery **twice**, so remove that. (If the reason you included jQuery twice was because it asks you to in the snippet, you don't have to if you already included it from somewhere else).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Welcome!");
});
```

```css
background-color:Teal;

}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: Gold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 25pt;
}
#p1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 300px;
}
#p2 {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#p3 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 300px;
}
#img1 {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
#img2 {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
a:link {
  color: gold;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: gold;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  color: lime;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    "Cute Cats"
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
  <h1> Cute Cats </h1>


  <p id="p1"> <img src="Tulip.jpg" alt="Cute Cat-Tulip" id="img1"> Find box a little too small and curl up with fur hanging out lick arm hair or sweet beast swat at dog, and chirp at birds that box? i can fit in that box. Spit up on light gray carpet instead of adjacent
    linoleum. Spill litter box, scratch at owner, destroy all furniture, especially couch find empty spot in cupboard and sleep all day, licks paws ptracy,intently sniff hand, or really likes hummus weigh eight pounds but take up a full-size bed. Chew
    the plant. Bleghbleghvomit my furball really tie the room together hiss and stare at nothing then run suddenly away and warm up laptop with butt lick butt fart rainbows until owner yells pee in litter box hiss at cats stretch, ooh, are those your
    $250 dollar sandals?

  </p>


  <p id="p2"> <img src="Tikki.jpg" alt="Cute Cat-Tikki" id="img2"> Slap kitten brother with paw spread kitty litter all over house, i could pee on this if i had the energy purr when being pet for nya nya nyan. Touch water with paw then recoil in horror eat all the
    power cords for chill on the couch table, annoy the old grumpy cat, start a fight and then retreat to wash when i lose so scratch me there, elevator butt refuse to come home when humans are going to bed; stay out all night then yowl like i am dying
    at 4am. Eat the rubberband the cat was chasing the mouse so demand to be let outside at once, and expect owner to wait for me as i think about it yet taco cat backwards spells taco cat furrier and even more furrier hairball for groom forever, stretch
    tongue and leave it slightly out, blep stand in front of the computer screen. Red light attracts my eyes, light must die, attack!

  </p>


  <p id="p3"> <img src="Maddi.jpg" alt="Cute Cat-Maddison" id="img1"> More napping, more napping all the napping is exhausting. Fish i must find my red catnip fishy fish who's the baby pet me pet me don't pet me scratch need to chase tail, but intently stare at the
    same spot, or i like frogs and 0 gravity. Meow to be let out thinking longingly about tuna brine or catasstrophe scratch, yet stare at wall turn and meow stare at wall some more meow again continue staring take a big fluffing crap cough hairball on
    conveniently placed pants. Lounge in doorway hiding behind the couch until lured out by a feathery toy. Sit on human give attitude, or meow go back to sleep owner brings food and water tries to pet on head, so scratch get sprayed by water because
    bad cat or lick butt. Stare at ceiling.

  </p>

</body>
```

Comment: Uh look at the question. There are no end quotes.

Comment: You are right, my bad. that's another problem on top of duplicated jQuery!

Comment: @HoomanBahreini would duplicate jQuery throw the code off? In the snippet I had, it seemed to work just fine and it had duplicate jQuery. (Obviously it's redundant to have duplicate jQuery, but would it really matter?)

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Also I think the only reason K.Camp had duplicate jQuery is because in the snippet, it asks you to select any libraries to add. He probably selected jQuery not thinking that since he already had it, he didn't have to add it again. The missing quotes as probably the mistake - not the duplicate jQuery.